# How to set database config variables for aws ecs in circle ci config.yml?

Tags: database, terraform, environment, amazon-ecs, circleci

How are you.

I am deploying go backend api to ecs using docker.

And I am using circle ci for it.

I need to set database config environment variables to run backend api, but I don't know how to set that info in circle ci.

I am initializing aws resource using terraform, do I need to set db config environment variables in terraform? or can I set it on circle ci config.yml?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define environment variables in the task definition so this will be available for your docker container in ECS.

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "backend-app" {
  family = "backend"

  container_definitions = <<EOF
[
  {
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "hostPort": 80,
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "containerPort": 3000
      }
    ],
    "environment": 
        [
            {
                "name": "NODE_ENV",
                "value":"production"
            },
            {
                 "name": "DB_HOST",
                 "value": "HOST_ADDRESS"
            },
            {
                "name": "DB_PASS",
                "value": "DB_PASSWORD"
            }
        ],
    "cpu": 1000,
    "memory": 1000,
    "image": "***.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/backend:latest",
    "name": "backend",

  }
]
EOF
}
```